# JQuery datepicker not working

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm completely new to JQuery and MVC.

I'm working on a pet project that uses both to learn them and I've hit my first snag.

I have a date field and I want to add the JQuery datepicker to the UI.  Here is what I have done:

Added    `<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
to the site.master

Inside my Create.aspx (View), I have

```
  <asp:Content ID="Create" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>
        Create a Task</h2>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("TaskForm"); %>
  </asp:Content>
```

and inside "TaskForm" (a user control) I have:

```
<label for="dDueDate">
            Due Date</label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("dDueDate",(Model.Task.TaskID > 0 ? string.Format("{0:g}",Model.Task.DueDate) : DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))) %>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#dDueDate").datepicker();
            });
        </script>
```

As you can see, the above checks to see if a task has an id > 0 (we're not creating a new one) if it does, it uses the date on the task, if not it defaults to today.  I would expect the datepicker UI element to show up, but instead I get:

"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method" on the `$("#dDueDate").datepicker();`

Ideas?  It is probably a very simple mistake, so don't over-analyze.  As I said, this is the first time I've dealt with MVC or JQuery so I'm lost as to where to start.

Comment: DatePicker is part of jQuery UI, not core jQuery, are you including both on your page?

Comment: You have to ask ASP to give you the "client ID" for the text box. I don't know how to do that, but somebody will.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I just selected the oldest answer since you were all right.  Added the JQuery UI and it worked like a charm.

Comment: -1, really?  Any explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`datepicker()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) is a [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download) method, it looks like you are only using jQuery.
You need to [download](http://jqueryui.com/download) and include jQuery UI in addition to jQuery

Make sure you download the version compatible with `jQuery 1.3.2`.

Answer (score 1):

You have included jQuery library, but not jQueryUI library. You have to do that with something like this:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jqueryui-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Of course this means that you have the jqueryui-1.8.1.min.js file there. You can use Google or MS CDN to retrieve this file from there.

Comment: To use 1.8.1 he'll need jQuery 1.4, not 1.3 like he's using right now.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to include [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) as well to get datepicker.